# JS отправка сообщения Enter. Конфликт с Shift+Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть код который служит для отправки сообщения при нажатии `enter`:

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).next('button').click();
  }
});
```

Но дело в том что когда я нажимаю Shift+Enter  для переноса строки, сообщение отправляется.

Что можно предпринять, дабы исправить это?

Comment: Не подскажите? - нет, не подскажем

Answer (score 2):

"Дабы"? Поелику!

```
if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
```

Comment: А вы пробовали нажать просто Enter в этом случае? Мне кажется сообщение вообще не отправиться.

Comment: @Владимир, всё ОК: если нажат `Enter` И не нажат `Shift` - выполняем. То, что нужно ТС.